# How to add rowspan class in admin grid?

Tags: magento2.2, custom-admin-grid

I just saw in Report > Order count page, if choosing "show by month", it will show the merged row blanks.

How can I set the rowspan class by code?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I override \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet in module at the end

Comment: Hey @Artick,  I am facing same question. Can you please share your code if you have ?